# game client updater

Tags: c#, auto-update

I'm a MMORPG Private Server dev and I'm looking forward to create an all in one updater for the user's clients because it is very annoying and lame to use patches that must be manually downloaded.

I'm new in C# but I already succeded at making my own launcher with my own interface and basic game start/options buttons and notice that is read from my webserver.

Now, I wanna make an integrated update function for that and I'm pretty lost, I have no idea where to start. This is what it would look like, it's just a concept

[image]

It will have the main button wich is used to start the game AND update it, basically when you open the program the button would write "UPDATE"  and is disabled(while it searches for new updates) and if any are found, it would turn into a clickable button, then after the updates are dowmloaded it would just change itself into "start game".

A progressbar for the overall update and another one to see the progress on the current file that is downloading only, all that with basic info like percentage and how much files need to be downloaded.

I need to find a way for the launcher to check the files on the webserver by HTTP method and check if they are same as client or newer ones so it dosent always redownload files already same version and also a method so that the updater will download the update as a compressed archive and auto extract and overwrite existing files when they are done downloading.

NOTE: The files being updated are not .exe, they mostly are textures/config files/maps/images/etc...

Comment: Please don't download executables over HTTP and then run them. HTTP is really easy to MitM.

Comment: No, the files that will be updated are textures, 3d models and other kind of stuff theres no exes, and even if there would be any, it would be compressed.

Comment: @user2030800: Being compressed isn't going to protect against an attack.  You need crypto--https or public-key encryption.

Comment: I understand but that won't happen, if I would ever need to update some exe files I'll just do a manual patch or something like that but the files I update are mostly textures/images/models/etc...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use HTTP, and not, say, just sockets?

Comment: My understanding is that you want the client to download the *entire* update as a *single* compressed archive; then there is probably no reason in having the *overall* progress bar, since there is actually only one file being downloaded. How would you advance the file counter by looking at the compressed stream?

Comment: Well all the servers I saw use their website.com/updater/ and put all the files in that folder, it's simple and works and I wanna stay with this method.

Comment: @damix911 I'm not very good in that but from what I saw in a launcher I previously bought and im not using more, it used ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll library to compress/uncompress files and it still showed number of files and all that stuff but, COMPRESS is not necessary it would not be a problem if there's no compression.

Comment: EDIT: I found out that method from my post above compressed each file individually, you would just put all your update files into a folder and set sn output folder, choose compression ratio and all files will be compressed individually. Like: image.bmp --> image.bmp.zip

Comment: You probably can advance progress bars during extraction, yes. But not during download if you zipped all files together. With the method you mention in the EDIT comment, you could have two progress bars also during download. Have a look at my answer, there are a few suggestions. I would start with practicing with the **HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse** pair and its integration with the progress bars. The other two thirds of the problem are 1) obtaining the list of updated files and 2) compression; for 1) I would hardcode the list of needed files, at least for now, and I'd skip 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll sketch a possible architecture for this system. It's incomplete, you should consider it a form of detailed pseudo-C#-code for the first half and a set of hints and suggestions for the second.

I believe you may need two applications for this:

- A C# WinForms client.
- A C# server-side application, maybe a web service.

I'll not focus on security issues on this answers, but they are obviously very important. I expect that security can be implemented at a higher level, maybe using SSL. The web service would run within IIS and implementing some form of security should be mainly a matter of configuration.

The server-side part is not strictly required, especially if you do't want compression; probably there is a way to configure your server so that it returns a easily parsable list of files when an HTTP request is made at **website.com/updater**. However it is more flexible to have a web service, and probably it's even easier to implement. You can start by looking at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx). If you do want compression, you can probably configure the server to transparently compress individual files. I'll try to sketch all possible variants.

In the case of a single update ZIP file, basically the updater web service should be able to answer two different requests; first, it can return a list of all game files, relative to the server directory **website.com/updater**, together with their last write timestamp (**GetUpdateInfo** method in the web service). The client would compare this list with the local files; some files may not exist anymore on the server (maybe the client must delete the local copy), some may not exist on the client (they are entirely new content), and some other files may exist both on the client and on the server, and in that case the client needs to check the last write time to determine if it needs the updated version. The client would build a list of the paths of these files, relative to the game content directory. The game content directory should mirror the server **website.com/updater** directory.

Second, the client sends this list to the server (**GetUpdateURL** in the web service). The server would create a ZIP containing the update and reply with its URL.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUpdater
{
    [OperationContract]
    public FileModified[] GetUpdateInfo();

    [OperationContract]
    public string GetUpdateURL();
}

[DataContract]
public class FileModified
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Path;

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Modified;
}

public class Updater : IUpdater
{
    public FileModified[] GetUpdateInfo()
    {
        // Get the physical directory
        string updateDir = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("website.com/updater");

        IList<FileModified> updateInfo = new List<FileModified>();

        foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(updateDir))
        {
            FileModified fm = new FileModified();
            fm.Path = // You may need to adjust path so that it is local with respect to updateDir
            fm.Modified = new FileInfo(path).LastWriteTime;
            updateInfo.Add(fm);
        }

        return updateInfo.ToArray();
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string GetUpdateURL(string[] files)
    {
        // You could use System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive and its
        // method CreateEntryFromFile. You create a ZipArchive by
        // calling ZipFile.Open. The name of the file should probably
        // be unique for the update session, to avoid that two concurrent
        // updates from different clients will conflict. You could also
        // cache the ZIP packages you create, in a way that if a future
        // update requires the same exact file you would return the same
        // ZIP.

        // You have to return the URL of the ZIP, not its local path on the
        // server. There may be several ways to do this, and they tend to
        // depend on the server configuration.

        return urlOfTheUpdate;
    }
}
```

The client would download the ZIP file by using **HttpWebRequest** and **HttpWebResponse** objects. To update the progress bar (you would have only one progress bar in this setup, check my comment to your question) you need to create a **BackgroundWorker**. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17979/Downloading-Files-in-NET-With-All-Information-Prog) and [this other article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35787/VB-NET-Background-File-Downloader) cover the relevant aspects (unfortunately the example is written in VB.NET, but it looks very similar to what would be in C#). To advance the progress bar you need to keep track of how many bytes you received:

```
int nTotalRead = 0;
HttpWebRequest theRequest;
HttpWebResponse theResponse;

...

byte[] readBytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = theResponse.GetResponseStream.Read(readBytes, 0, 4096);

nTotalRead += bytesread;
int percent = (int)((nTotalRead * 100.0) / length);
```

Once you received the file you can use **System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ExtractToDirectory** to update your game.

If you don't want to explicitly compress the files with .NET, you can still use the first method of the web service to obtain the list of updated file, and copy the ones you need on the client using an **HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse** pair for each. This way you can actually have two progress bars. The one that counts files will simply be set to a percentage like:

```
int filesPercent = (int)((nCurrentFile * 100.0) / nTotalFiles);
```

If you have another way to obtain the list, you don't even need the web service.

If you want to individually compress your files, but you can't have this feature automatically implemented by the server, you should define a web service with this interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUpdater
{
    [OperationContract]
    public FileModified[] GetUpdateInfo();

    [OperationContract]
    public string CompressFileAndGetURL(string path);
}
```

In which you can ask the server to compress a specific file and return the URL of the compressed single-file archive.

**Edit - Important**

Especially in the case that your updates are very frequent, you need to pay special attention to *time zones*.

**Edit - An Alternative**

I should restate that one of the main issues here is obtaining the list of files in the *current release* from the server; this file should include the last write time of each file. A server like Apache can provide such a list for free, although usually it is intended for *human* consumption, but it is easily parsable by a program, nevertheless. I'm sure there must be some script/extension to have that list formatted in an even more machine-friend way.

There is another way to obtain that list; you could have a text file on the server that, for every *game content* file, stores its last write time or, maybe even better, a progressive release number. You would compare release numbers instead of dates to check which files you need. This would protext yourself from time zone issues. In this case however you need to maintain a local copy of this list, because files have no such thing as a release number, but only a name and a set of dates.

Comment: One thousand thanks to your very detailed explanation, this is one huge piece of help for me, I will examinate it in detail and try to do my updater by different methods. Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: For the way files version are checked, what about a client side little program that will takes the files of a directory and create a list with them, their directory and md4 hashes. Updater will get that list, compare files and download required ones

Answer (score 1):

This is a wide and varied question, with several answers that could be called 'right' depending on various implementation requirements.  Here are a few ideas...

1. My approach would be to use `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1` to generate a list of hash codes for each game asset.  The updater can then download the list, compare it to the local file system (caching the locally-generated hashes for efficiency) and build a list of new/changed files to be downloaded.
2. If the game data uses archives, the process gets a bit more involved, since you don't want to download a huge archive when only a single small file inside may have been changed.  In this case you'd want to hash each file within the archive and provide a method for downloading those contained files, then update the archive using the files you download from the server.
3. Finally, give some thought to using a Binary Diff/Patch algorithm to reduce the bandwidth requirements by downloading smaller patch files when possible.  In this case the client would request a patch that updates from the current version to the latest version of a file, sending the hash of the local file so the server knows which patch to send.  This requires you to maintain a stack of patches on the server for each previous version you want to be able to patch from, which might be more than you're interested in.

Here are some links that might be relevant:

- [SHA1 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) - Microsoft documentation for SHA1 hashing class
- [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) - using 7Zip in C#
- [bsdiff.net](https://github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net) - a .NET library implementing bsdiff

Oh, and consider using a multi-part downloader to better saturate the available bandwidth at the client end.  This results in higher load on the server(s), but can greatly improve the client-side experience.

Comment: Thank you for this lost od ideas, I will check them out and try :) Thanks alot!